# Swift presenting new view after user sends email from MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: swift, email, segue, transition

Goal: after user clicks “Send” from an MFMailComposeViewController, dismiss the compose view and have a confirmation view already presented behind it.

I created an email composer from a user tap with:

```
let emailComposer = EmailComposer()

@IBAction func ok(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let confirguredEmailComposer = emailComposer.configuredMailComposeViewController(to: ["self@self.com"], subject: "Testing", body: "Testy test testing")

    if emailComposer.canSendMail(){
        present(confirguredEmailComposer, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        showSendMailError(title: "Email Error", message: "That didn't work out so well")
    }

}
```

The EmailComposer class has a delegate function that correctly dismisses the composition view and captures a result:

```
class EmailComposer: NSObject, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    func canSendMail() -> Bool {
        return MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()
    } // close func
    func configuredMailComposeViewController(to: [String], subject: String, body: String) -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(to)
        mailComposerVC.setSubject(subject)
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(body, isHTML: true)
        return mailComposerVC
    } // close func
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true) {
            switch result {
            case .cancelled:
                print ("Zapp Canceled")
            case .saved:
                print ("Your email has been saved to send later")
            case .sent:
                print ("Zapp Sent!")
            case .failed:
                print ("Mail sent failure: \([error!.localizedDescription])")
            } // close switch 
        } // close controller.dismiss completion handler
    } // close func
} // close class
```

I cannot figure out how to present the confirmation view after the user sends the email.

Also, is it better to initiate the transition from within the EmailComposer's delegate method, or from the view controller that created the EmailComposer instance?

And lastly, is it better to create a segue in IB and use it to execute the transition, or do it all in code, or it this just a matter of personal preference?

Comment: Your only option is to present it from the delegate method after you have dismissed the mail composer.

Comment: You should subclass MFMailComposeViewController instead of NSObject and create a convenience initializer instead of configuredMailComposeViewController method https://gist.github.com/leodabus/587a5146c1544020fae00260126749ea

Comment: Leo, yes that is much more elegant than what I had.  Thanks!  Now how about transitioning to the confirmation view such that as the compose view slides away the confirmation view is already behind it?

Comment: rmaddy, thanks!  any tips on executing the transition programatically from the delegate function?

Comment: @niblettes you are welcome. Please edit your question and try to make it more clear. Add your actual code and how you are trying to present the new view controller or performSegue withIdentifier and what is not working